# SQL Server - select Top 2 in Inner Join

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, select

I am new to sql server, i am having Join with two tables. The problem is One table say [TABLE1] is having only 1 row but the other table say [TABLE2] can have many rows.

i wanted to create a Query which can retrieve 1 row from TABLE1 and 2 top rows from TABLE2.

note: Both the tables have 1 common column so i have created Join.

I tried using TOP 2 - but this didn't worked

```
    select T1.Col1 , Top 2 T2.Col1, ....
    from TABLE1 T1
    inner join TABLE2 T2
    ON T1.commonRow =  T2.commonRow
```

Below is the structure of table1 & table2

```
    TABLE 1      TABLE2 
    -----------------------------
     DATA        COMMENTS 1
                 COMMENTS 2
                 COMMENTS 3
                 COMMENTS 4
```

can some one help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TOP keyword needs to be after the SELECT and before the column names.

See SQL Server Books Online > SELECT Clause (Transact-SQL) > Syntax.

You don't need a subquery. So this should work.

```
SELECT TOP(2) T1.Col1 , T2.Col1, ....
    FROM Table1 T1
        INNER JOIN Table2 T2
            ON T1.commonRow =  T2.commonRow;
```

Note that it is current practice to use parentheses after TOP.

Normally you would specify an ORDER BY clause so the TOP however many is meaningful.

See SQL Server Books Online > TOP (Transact-SQL).

For example, using the AdventureWorks sample database:

```
SELECT TOP(5) H.CustomerID, D.OrderQty
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader H
        INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail D
            ON D.SalesOrderID = H.SalesOrderID
    ORDER BY D.OrderQty DESC;
```

Results are:

```
CustomerID  OrderQty
----------- --------
29818       44
29580       41
29913       40
29818       40
29913       39

(5 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
select  T1.Col1 ,T2.Col1, ....
from TABLE1 T1
inner join (SELECT TOP(2)* FROM TABLE2) T2
ON T1.commonRow =  T2.commonRow
```

Comment: When i used above query i am getting no results.